# Django Haystack Elastic Search maximum value for indexable CharField

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, full-text-search, django-haystack

I was wondering whats the maximum value for an indexable CharField in Django Haytack with elasticsearch?

I am asking this, because I am getting a timeout when I try to index a specific charfield that has a size of at least `736166`.

This seems to be pretty big for me, but is there a way for me to avoid that timeout, or am I not supposed to be using fields this big?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there was not enough memory. Upgrading from 2GB to 4GB in my VM fixed the problem.